# Radiation from collision of two charged particles

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, collision

Consider a collision between two electrons.  Since each particle is accelerated during the collision, I assume each radiates energy according to the Larmor formula.

Question 1:  How much energy is radiated during the collision?  I'd be happy with the "simplest" case of the head-on collision in the center-of-mass frame, but am curious how one would go about calculating it, or else a demonstration that it's zero.

Question 2: Since it seems there must be some energy radiated, doesn't this mean that charged particle collisions *cannot* be elastic?  And if that's true, does that mean that *any* matter-matter interaction is dissipative, even at the microscopic level?  (Gravitational interactions radiate gravity waves, which carry energy away, so we already know that they are dissipative.)